# Unknown extra link appears in my navigation links (debugging help)

Tags: html, css, web

I'm currently learning and practicing by coding my own website (so I'm a newbie), but I can't figure out why I have an extra link to the left of my first navigation links.

It only goes away if I delete my navigation links (HTML side) or if I taken away padding under the navigation in CSS, which I need to style.

This is an image of the page when rendered. The extra link is purple due to my mouse hovering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdEqk.png

```css
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: cadetblue;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .siteheader {
            display: inline;
        }
        .sitelogo {
            float:left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .sociallinks {
            display: inline;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-top: 53px;
            margin-bottom: 53px;
        }
        .sitenav {
            display: inline;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .sitenav a {
            background: red;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 5%;

        }
        li a:hover {
            background-color:#5d77dd;
        }

    </style>
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
<title>Site Name Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav role="navigation">    
<div class="siteheader">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sitelogo"><img src="../Img/TestingLogo.png" alt="Site Logo"></a>
    <ul>
    <li class="sociallinks"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../Img/IconGrayToneByAlfredo/facebook.jpg" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
    <li class="sociallinks"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../Img/IconGrayToneByAlfredo/twitter.jpg" alt="Twiiter"</a></li>
    <li class="sociallinks"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../Img/IconGrayToneByAlfredo/instagram.jpg" alt="Instagram"</a></li>
    <li class="sociallinks"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../Img/IconGrayToneByAlfredo/pinterest.jpg" alt="Pinterest"</a></li>
    <li class="sociallinks"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="../Img/IconGrayToneByAlfredo/tumblr.jpg" alt="Tumblr"</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li class="sitenav"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sitenav"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Work</a>
    <li class="sitenav"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="sitenav"><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a></li>
    <li class="sitenav"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Store</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me get rid of the extra link and thanks for any help!

Comment: you are not closing the image tags of the social icons ie. you forgot to write `/>` at the end of the tag

Comment: can you just copy your code with question

Comment: I've add ">" and it works! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you please not post code as screenshots, but as actual code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll look up how to next time I ask a question.

Comment: @LisaPizza you better look it up now and improve this very question. The down votes might influence your ability to ask questions in the future. The [help] was various articles to guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've add ">" and it works, as suggested by Immortal Dude (it shows up as a comment instead of an answer so I don't know how to mark it as such).

Thanks everyone for your input!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could copy paste the code.

I did notice line 61 is missing a closing `li` tag, so maybe you can try that.

Comment: `li` elements don't need closing tags (in HTML). They're allowed, but unnecessary.